# Find entity with table name and key value

Tags: entity-framework

For example, I have this :

```
    private object GetEntityFromKey(ObjectStateEntry entry)
    {
        object entity = null;

        var key = entry.EntityKey;
        var keyValues = entry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues;

        return entity; 
    }
```

My question is how can I retrieve the entity using two known factors : `key` and `keyValues` ?

I need this to be dynamic, so the returned's type is `object`

I can get the entity using :

```
this.GetObjectByKey(key)
```

but this will return the entity from the `ObjectStateManager` instead of the datasource

I'm using DataBase First approach. The reason I'm doing this because I need to compare the new and old record for auditing purpose.

Comment: Are you using code first?

Comment: @Derek Hi Derek, I'm using Database First approach

Comment: @Derek I also edited my question, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in EF v. 4.2 or higher, you can create a `DbContext` from an existing `ObjectContext` instance. Once you've got this `DbContext` you can use its `Find` method to get an object by key.

All wrapped up in one method, and omitting null checks, I suppose this could work for you:

```
public static class ObjectContextExtensions
{
    public static T GetOriginalEntity<T>(this ObjectContext oc, T localEntity)
        where T : class
    {
        ObjectStateEntry ose;
        oc.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(localEntity, out ose);
        var keys = ose.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select(k => k.Value).ToArray();
        using (var db = new DbContext(oc, false))
        {
            return db.Set<T>().Find(keys);
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
Entity entity;

using(var objContext = new MyObjectContext())
{
    entity = objContext.Entities.Single(e => e.Id == someId);

    ...
}

using(var objContext = new MyObjectContext())
{
    var entityOrg = objContext.GetOriginalEntity(entity);
}
```

You have to use a new context in `GetOriginalEntity`, because the `Find` method first tries to get the entity from the context's cache.

Comment: Hi, Thanks but I'm using EF 4.1. Hope this can help others!